# Can't upload PDF using carrierwave on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, heroku, carrierwave, ruby-on-rails-4.2

In my rails 4 app, I'm using carrierwave to upload files to google cloud storage. I'm able to successfully upload image files, but pdfs are not working. It shows following error:

**You are not allowed to upload "pdf" files, allowed types: jpg, jpeg, gif, png**

Here is my uploader:-

```
# encoding: utf-8
require 'carrierwave/processing/mime_types'
class AttachmentUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  include CarrierWave::MimeTypes

  storage :fog

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  process :set_content_type

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png pdf)
  end

end
```

I don't know what's wrong with this code.

And here's the attachment model

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :attachment, AttachmentUploader

  # Associations

  belongs_to :attached_item, polymorphic: true

  # Validations

  validates_presence_of :attachment
  validates_integrity_of :attachment

  # Callbacks

  before_save :update_attachment_attributes

  # Delegate

  delegate :url, :size, :path, to: :attachment

  # Virtual attributes

  alias_attribute :filename, :original_filename

  private

  def update_attachment_attributes
    if attachment.present? && attachment_changed?
      self.original_filename = attachment.file.original_filename
      self.content_type = attachment.file.content_type
    end
  end
end
```

**Update**:
When testing on local machine it works but not on heroku. On development env it works without issue and I can check file uploaded to google storage. But on heroku it displays error "You are not allowed to upload "pdf" files, allowed types: jpg, jpeg, gif, png"

**Update**:
There is another uploader in my app, ImageUploader. When I set its extension_white_list to include pdf, it makes attachment_uploader work as well. How's that happening. Do I need to have same extension_white_list in my all uploaders?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post the complete error log, do you have any validations on model for this?

Comment: Are you using an image field by any chance?

Comment: odd. What happens if you put `pdf` at the beginning of the list?

Comment: I'm using rails_admin and uploading file using it. It's supposed to work.

Comment: Remove this `validates_integrity_of :attachment` and try once.

Comment: @Deep Still the same error.

Comment: @Deep It works on local machine but not on heroku.

Comment: @tompave setting pdf at begining doesn't make any difference. I set my another uploader to include pdf as well and it started working!!!

Comment: I took a break, and looked at my code again. There must something very silly I must be doing. I indeed was.

And I solved it. 
Issue was Duplicate class name in uploader, filename was correct so didn't  look at the top. 
Sorry for wasting your time. Thanks!